# Property 'then' does not exist on type 'MediaObject'

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic-native

I'm attempting to create a simple media player with Ionic 3 and the MediaObject from Ionic-Native is giving me some trouble.

> app.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
    import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
    import { MediaPlugin, MediaObject } from '@ionic-native/media';

    import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'app.html'
    })
    export class MyApp {
      rootPage:any = HomePage;
      file:MediaObject = undefined;

      constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private media: MediaPlugin) {

        const onStatusUpdate = (status) => console.log(status);

        media.create('./path/to/file.mp3', onStatusUpdate)
          .then((file: MediaObject) => {``
            this.file = file;
        });
      }

      play() {
        this.file.play();
      }
    }
```

My issue is that when I serve the project I get "Property 'then' does not exist on type 'MediaObject'"

From my understanding media.create SHOULD be returning a MediaObject promise that once resolved will allow me to use the MediaObject.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[the doc says](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media/#create) `create` Returns: `MediaObject` not a `promise`

Comment: I swear on me mum, the documentation was updated within half an hour of me posting this question. Thanks for pointing out the change!

Comment: hahaha, yeah might have been, I see the latest release 3.1.0 was released yesterday, maybe it took time for the site to update. happy to help :)